# Use async with action result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I would like Residency to return a `Task<ActionResult>`.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Residency() 
{
    DBResponse DataSource = await Residency_Manager.Residency_REPORT();
}
```

Below is the DBResponse class:

```
public DBResponse(Int32 statusCode, string message, Object data)
{
    this.StatusCode = statusCode;
    this.Message = message;
    this.Data = data;
}
```

When I await the Residency_REPORT function it returns a DBResponse object and shows the error below.
[image: Error Message]

Comment: show us the signature for `Residency_REPORT`

Comment: `Residency_Manager.Residency_REPORT` should return a `Task<DBResponse>` and should be an async method. Also you should not be passing this many parameters to it. Why are these not classes?

Comment: Don't post links to images. Copy and paste the code and error message itself. `await` doesn't make a method asychronous by magic, it *awaits* an already asychronous method. If `Residency_REPORT` doesn't return a Task you can't await it. This isn't related to ASP.NET MVC

Comment: Possibly you need a `Task.Run` with `return View()` or something like that, which is awaitable by `return await`. However `Residency_Manager.Residency_REPORT` possibly isn't awaitable in current state.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto web requests *already* run on their own thread. Using Task.Run will only transfer execution to a new thread, wasting the original thread *and* causing a performance hit due to the thread switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Residency_Manager.Residency_REPORT()` is not an async method, so you cannot call it with `await`.

The simple solution: do not implement `Residency` as an async method, since there's nothing there you need async for. If other code in there *is* async, just remove the await in front of the call:

`DBResponse DataSource = Residency_Manager.Residency_REPORT();`

The other simple solution: implement Residency_REPORT to be async and have it return a `Task<DBResponse>`

Comment: If there is no async code being called from this action, then you should change the signature of your action also from: `public async Task<ActionResult> Residency()` To: 
`public ActionResult Residency()` If `Residency_Manager.Residency_REPORT()` returns a `Task<DBResponse>` then this method should be named: `Residency_Manager.Residency_REPORTAsync()`